# Erro ao gerar laço de descendentes (arvore genealogica)

Tags: php, pdf, dompdf

Esse codigo é dentro do script do DOMPDF, nele eu pego uma ave cadastrada e seto as variaveis da mesma no `$ra`, até aí tudo bem, mas esse sistema é uma arvore genealógica e eu devo sempre perguntar ao sistema se aquela ave tem pai e mãe, se sim, mostra o pai e mae, se não, para o loop, o que ta acontecendo é que nas duas outras consultas, se a primeira ave tem pai e mãe cadastrado eu devo pagar o avô e avó maternos e avô e avó maternos e assim por diante, o que ta acontecendo é que os `ifs` para saber se a ave tem pai e mãe cadastrado não ta funcionando, se não tem ele mostra, mas se tem dá erro ao gerar o pdf.

A pergunta é, como faço a condicional caso a ave não tenha cadastrado o pai ($rb) e mãe ($rc)?

O erro tá aqui:

```
$rb = isset($ra["pai"]) ? $rb["nome"] : NULL;
$rc = isset($ra["mae"]) ? $rc["nome"] : NULL;
```

```
    $cmd = db_connect()->prepare("SELECT * FROM genealogia WHERE idave = $idave");
    $cmd->execute();
    $resultado = $cmd->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

   foreach ($resultado as $ra){

if($ra['pai'] > 0){
           $selecionapai = db_connect()->prepare("SELECT * FROM genealogia WHERE idave = '".$ra['pai']."'");
           $selecionapai->execute();
           foreach($selecionapai as $rb){
               }}     

if($ra['mae'] > 0){
           $selecionamae = db_connect()->prepare("SELECT * FROM genealogia WHERE idave = '".$ra['mae']."'");
           $selecionamae->execute();
           foreach($selecionamae as $rc){
}}

$rb = isset($ra["pai"]) ? $rb["nome"] : NULL;
$rc = isset($ra["mae"]) ? $rc["nome"] : NULL;

//Criando o código HTML que será transformado em pdf
/*$dompdf->loadHtml('
<div style="width:96%; height: 965px; border: solid 3px #333; padding: 2%">
<div style="style="margin: 0 auto; width: 100%; height: 60px">
<h2">Cadastro Único de aves - CUA</h2>
</div>
'.$ra["nome"].'
'.$rb.'
'.$rc.'
<br>
</div>

');   */
       echo $ra["nome"].'<br>';
       echo $rb.'<br>';
       echo $rc.'<br>';
}
```

Comment: Sempre poste o código em texto, não em imagem.

Comment: Tentei, mas dá erro, só mostra uma parte do codigo

Comment: Consegui adicionar o codigo

Comment: Mas qual é mesmo a duvida?

Comment: O dompdf não gera o arquivo se a arvore (o campo pai e mãe no banco de dados) estiverem cadastrados, o que quero fazer é pegar a mae e o pai de cada animal, por diante, exemplo: animal (pai | mae) (pai do pai  | mãe do pai  | pai da mãe  | mãe da mãe) ... pegando assim, o animal, o pai, avô, o bisavô... Mas o codigo deve ter alguma condicional errada, pois não ta gerando, observe que o $rd1 e $rd2 são os avô paterno e avó paterno do $ra, por exemplo.

Comment: Com as informações que você colocou não há possibilidade de resposta, pois, não existe nenhuma pergunta. @AugustoVasques já lhe orientou e eu reforço, dê um lida no [Guia de sobrevivência do Stack Overflow em Português](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/8045/guia-de-sobreviv%c3%aancia-do-stack-overflow-em-portugu%c3%aas) e tenta melhorar seu texto para que alguém possa efim lhe ajudar.